# '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

Tags: qt, qlist

Just getting into QT, and I'm attempting to create an array of LineEdit text boxes.

error: C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

on the following line:

```
QList<QLineEdit *> leBetList = parentWidget.findChildren<QLineEdit *>("leBet0");
```

I have 5 QLineEdit boxes, named leBet0,leBet1, etc.

Here is the rest of the code:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QList>
#include <QString>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QString sBetStreet[5];
     int iBetStreet[5];

     QList<QLineEdit *> leBetList = parentWidget.findChildren<QLineEdit *>("leBet0");


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        sBetStreet[i] = ui->leBetList[i]->text();
        iBetStreet[i]=sBetStreet[i].toInt();
    }

    int iBetResult=iBetStreet[0]+iBetStreet[1];
    QString sBetResult;
    sBetResult=QString::number(iBetResult);

    ui->teOutput->setText(sBetResult);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parentWidget` is a function. You need to call it

```
parentWidget()->findChildren ...
```

The poor compiler's error message is probably referring to its internal representation, which apparently applies an implicit `&` operation on the member function name.

Comment: This allowed the application to build, however the program crashes when i press the "run" button with an error: ASSERT failure is QList<T>::operator: "index out of range"